# Simple Junit Test method for this Class using mocks/stubs

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

im very new to Junit, and i was wondering if someone could give me an example of of how to write a unit test for this method? of even if you could point me in the right direction, as i am unsure about the use of mocks and stubs, if i need them in this particular situation, when to use them ect...

```
public static String[] getDirectoryList(String parentPath, String directoryNames) {
    final List<String> directoryList= new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] directoryArray = directoryNames.split(", ");

    for(String directories : directoryArray){
        directories.trim();
        directories = parentPath + directories;
        directoryList.add(directories);
    }

    if (directoryList.size()==0)
        return null;
    else
        return directoryList.toArray(new String[directoryList.size()]);

}
```

Comment: have you tried anything? Did you read documentation?

Comment: You don't have the need for mocks to test this method; also, I see a bug in it ;)

Comment: Hi, yea i've read the documentation but am a little confused, with all this mocks and stubs stuff! thanks @fge for pointing out i didnt need mocks, also if you could enlighten me on the bug, that would be great...

Comment: Hint: `String` is immutable... Look at the first statement of your `for` loop.

Comment: OK so i should not be using .trim(), as i am not changing the String object, but rather the reference...

Comment: I think @fge is getting at the fact that the call to `trim()` in your code will be completely irrelevant as the value that it returns is not assigned anywhere. Also, if you're trimming the strings anyway, why not just split the initial string on `","`

Comment: Or just split on `"\\s*,\\s*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this case you don't need mock.

```
    @Test
    public void testWithOneDirectory() {
       String[] directoryList = getDirectoryList("/", "home");
       Assert.assertArrayEquals(" sould equal to on dir",ONE_DIR, directoryList);
    }

    @Test
    public void testShouldThrowException{
       try{
          String[] directoryList = getDirectoryList("/", null);
          fail("Should throw exception when arg is null");
       }
       catch(Exception e) {}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You usually mock dependencies in order to ensure that you are only testing code you want to test.

For example: if your method is calling a DAO, then you need to mock that DAO to ensure that the DAO's implementation details do not affect the results of your test (essentially, you want to isolate your code).

In your case, since the method you are testing does not have any dependencies, you don't need any mocks.